# how do you get job id for splunk saved search in python

Tags: python, python-requests, splunk

I am trying to retrieve job id from splunk using python.

when I do this in curl, it works. It prints out the sid number.

```
curl -u <username>:<password> -k https://example.com:8089/services/search/jobs -d search="search interface*"
```

I get:

```
<response>
  <sid>1899999967</sid>
</response>
```

I need to convert this curl code to python request, I tried this:

```
res=requests.get('https://example.com:8089/services/search/jobs', params= ('-d search='search interface*'"), auth=(<username>:<password>), verify=False)
```

I get a huge list of search results that incude other saved search results. I only need saved search interface*

Any ideas what I am doing here wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well this a 3 Part process.

First Part is run the query. (Which you did.)

Secound, check if the search ran. (Succesfully) `curl -u 'admin' https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs/1289517421.3076`

Thrid retrieve the results, in xml or csv.

```
curl -u 'admin' https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs/1289517421.3076/results -d"output_mode=csv"
```